# Firefox not catching "undefined" error in javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have some javascript code which calls a servlet with parameters based on the selected option from a SELECT list. It is possible that there will be no options in the `selectCampaigns(account)` so there is a `try` and `catch`.

The code in the `catch` should be called if,

`var selectedCampaign = selectCampaigns.options[selectCampaigns.selectedIndex].text;`

fails. This works in both chrome and IE but in firefox it gives a `TypeErrror`,

`TypeError: selectCampaigns.options[selectCampaigns.selectedIndex] is undefined`

which does not trigger the `catch`. May I have some suggestions on how to handle this? (in addition firefox does not show any of the alerts that I have inserted for debugging).

```
function selectcampaign(account) {
    alert('alert1');
    var selectCampaigns = document.getElementById("campaignSelect");
    var urlstrg = "http://localhost:8080/SalesPoliticalMapping/OrgChart";

    try {
        var selectedCampaign = selectCampaigns.options[selectCampaigns.selectedIndex].text;
        urlstrg = "http://localhost:8080/SalesPoliticalMapping/OrgChart?account=" + account +   "&campaign=" + selectedCampaign;
    } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
        urlstrg = "http://localhost:8080/SalesPoliticalMapping/OrgChart?account=" + account;
    } finally {
        window.location.href = urlstrg;
    }
};
```

Comment: May I suggest you to check for `undefined` instead of using a `try ... catch` block? As you know, this is a performance killer (and is more reliable!)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better test the value instead of dealing with errors.

```
function selectcampaign(account) {
    var selectCampaigns = document.getElementById("campaignSelect");
    var urlstrg = "http://localhost:8080/SalesPoliticalMapping/OrgChart?account=" + account;

    if(selectCampaigns.options[selectCampaigns.selectedIndex]) {
        urlstrg += "&campaign=" + selectCampaigns.options[selectCampaigns.selectedIndex].text;
    }

    window.location.href = urlstrg;
};
```

Comment: Again this works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox I get an error "TypeError: selectCampaigns.options[selectCampaigns.selectedIndex] is undefined" in the console and the window.location.href is never reached.

Comment: What if `selectCampaigns` is `null`?

Comment: Same problem: chrome is fine but firefox gives "TypeError: selectCampaigns.options[selectCampaigns.selectedIndex] is undefined"! I also have an issue that alerts are not working. Could this be related?

Comment: @user3718259 I don't see an alert here. And as Johan said, are you sure that the select exists ?

Comment: Please accept my apologies. I had deleted and re-installed firefox but the cache still had an old version of the code. The code from sebcap is now working. Many thanks.